# grep restart script if not running

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Hi guys i'm running into an issue here that I need to have a nohup php script run in the background and make sure it's always running and restarted if it crashes.
I run the following bash script using a crontab job every minute,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep script_name
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  nohup php path/to/script/script_name &
fi
```

I kill my script manually but it is never restarted, I am currently in the need to have this work in centos 6.5. I have tested the same configuration in centos 7.1 and it is working. Possibly is there an alternative that would work in centos 6.5 ?

Comment: Does centos still use inittab?

Comment: good question, though I am using /etc/crontab and I have other non related cronjobs that are working with that

Comment: Smacks of a respawn entry, to me

Comment: When i run my script manually without crontab it works, it tells me that the script is already running and doesn't start another instance. I would know if it wouldn't be working because nohup would restart the script again and I would have 2 instances of the script running at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use systemd; I don't know whether that is available in centos 6.5, though.

Without systemd: It may be easier to run a script which starts and restarts your PHP script instead of having one that checks for the script. Something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
while ! php path/to/script/script_name; do
    :
done
```

This wrapper script may be started with nohup if necessary.

In general you should rather use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep --full script_name
```

Comment: unfortunately centos 6.5 doesn't have systemd. The point of the crontab in my scenario would be to act as a "failover" in case that my nohup scripts crashes for whatever reason, it would restart it automatically. If I understand correctly, with this wrapper script running my php script, I wouldn't need to have my php script loop and wouldn't have to run the php script with nohup ? Instead I would just run the wrapper script with nohup ?

Comment: @Delbane Yes. Running the wrapper script through nohup has the advantage that the output of all instances of your script is written to the file `nohup.out`. Otherwise each instance overwrites the previous output.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will test this out and mark as resolved if it works!